# ¿Cómo soluciono este error al usar gráficos en Java?

Tags: java

El código da error en la parte que se declara el MouseAdapter y no se que es. El error se da en las llaves de cierre. Lo que quiero hacer es que al pulsar el botón con el mouse (utilizando el mouseListener) se muestre el mensaje "Se ha clickeado el mouse con éxito".

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ventana1 extends JFrame{

Ventana1(){
    setTitle("Mouse Listener");
    setBounds(200,200,400,400);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Container cp=getContentPane();
    JButton bt1=new JButton("Botón");
    cp.add(bt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ventana1 ventana=new Ventana1();
}

    bt1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev){
            System.out.println("Se ha clickeado el mouse con éxito");
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: El listener debe definirse dentro de un método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El listener debe definirse después de crear el botón y dentro de un mètodo.

```
    Ventana1() {
        setTitle("Mouse Listener");
        setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        JButton bt1 = new JButton("Botón");

        //Define listener para eventos de mouse a botòn.
        bt1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                System.out.println("Se ha clickeado el mouse con éxito");
            }
        });

         cp.add(bt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
```

Si deseas crear una UI con lo que mencionas, este es un Ejemplo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse Listener");
    frame.setBounds(200,200,400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton bt1 = new JButton("Botón");
    bt1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                System.out.println("Se ha clickeado el mouse con éxito");
            }
        });

    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.add(bt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  }

}
```